# jVectorMap: Update Scale

Tags: jquery, json, jvectormap

I'm having a hard time updating the scale of the region in a map created with jVectorMap (whereas updating values with new data works just fine):

```
{"data":{"title":"A or B?","values":{"DE":"A","AT":"A","CH":"B"},"scale":{"A":"#FFCC00","B":"#00AEB5"}}}

worldmap.series.regions[0].setValues(dataCountry.data.values); //ok, values are being updated
worldmap.series.regions[0].setScale(dataCountry.data.scale); //TypeError: this.scale.setScale is not a function
```

Any hint is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final solution I came up with is a more of a work-around: **whenever there's new data** (values/scale) to be pushed to an existing map, I simply **create a new map** replacing the old. I'm sure that using the provided methods setValues() and setScale() would be way more efficient, but it just wouldn't work in my case for whatever reason.